# print out for java exercise explanation

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the following Java exercise. Even running the debugger I don't understand the details of the second and third printout:

> 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> 1, 2, 4, 4
>
> 1, 2, 4, 8

I understand that the first print is the array as it is, second line prints [2] element of the array and third line [3] element. Here is the code:

```
public class TR1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] v =  {1, 2, 3, 4 };
        print(v);
        x(v, v[2] - 1);
        print(v);
        x(v, v[3] - 1);
        print(v);
    }

    public static void x(int array[], int y)
    {
        array[y] = array[y - 1] * 2;
    }

    public static void print(int array[])
    {
        System.out.print(array[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(", " + array[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: eg. why is it printed 8 ?

Comment: Nice question for a newbie ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I agree, I think that this is a very good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what this method does :

```
public static void x(int array[], int y)
    {
        array[y] = array[y - 1] * 2;
    }
```

It takes the value at index `y-1`, multiplies it by `2`, then assigns this result to the index `y` .

Starting array : `{1,2,3,4}`

The call with `v[2] - 1` takes the value at index `2` (which is `3`), and substracts `1`, so we have `y = 2`.

From what we said before, the method takes the value at index `1` (`y-1`) which is `2`, multiplies it by `2` so we get `4`, and assigns that to the index `2` (`y`) .

Current array : `{1,2,4,4}`

The call with `v[3] - 1` takes the value at index `3` (which is `4`), and substracts `1`, so we have `y = 3`.

From what we said before, the method takes the value at index `2` (`y-1`) which is `4`, multiplies it by `2` so we get `8`, and assigns that to the index `3` (`y`) .

Current array : `{1,2,4,8}`

Comment: very nice explanation for a newbie, all clear now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Lets briefly walk you through the first things that happen. You start with this array:

```
1 2 3 4
```

No surprise when printing that.

Then you run:

```
x(v, v[2] -1 ) ... evaluates to

x(v, 3 - 1)    ... evaluates to

x(v, 2)
```

Which changes the array based on:

```
array[y] = array[y - 1] * 2;
```

Lets insert y as 2 (see above):

```
array[2] = array[1] * 2;

array[2] = 2 * 2;
```

leading to:

```
1, 2, 4, 4
```

So, the real answer is: you don't even need a debugger. A piece of paper, a pen and a bit of thinking is even more efficient to uncover the "secrets" here.

Answer (score 1):

`print` always prints the entire array. `x` and `y` are making changes to the array in between.

Keep in mind that `v[x]` is just an integer. For example, `v[2]` is initialy just `3`, so `v[2] - 1 = 2`. Hence it modifies `v[2]` between the first and second call to `print`.

Comment: many thank, I get this, but [3] is initially 4 and it prints 8

Comment: @matrix Actually, [3] is changed to 8 *second* time `x` is called. The first time `x` is called, `[2]` is changed to `4`.